# Meaning of "to wrestle places from their surveillance grids"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> His concern is tracing the individual and personal history in the seemingly banal, and wrestling anonymous places from their recording and surveillance grids.

What could "wrestling something from their something" mean?

Does it mean that the person is struggling to get the anonymous places out of their surveillance grids? Or does it mean that the person is struggling against the anonymous places in their surveillance grids?

Or does it mean something else entirely?

I'm reading through an artist's introduction and there are so many expressions I understand only partially. I do get the "nuance" of the expression, but if I were to put it in my own words, I could not.

What could that sentence possibly mean?

Comment: You wrote *[wresting](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wresting)* but asked about *[wrestling](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wrestling)*. Which is it?

Comment: I found the artist's introduction you mention, and frankly I would not bother with that sort of pretentious tosh that confuses lack of clarity with lyricism and poetic brilliance.

Comment: I would read *wrestling* here as a malapropism; *wresting* would make a whole lot more sense.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the artist is trying to liberate the anonymous places from their banal existence as data sets in the surveillance and recording grids (more like "wrestle the places free from..."). It's a parallel idea; just as he is trying to liberate individual histories from banality, he is trying to reclaim places as well.